# Hibernate one to many relationship example

Tags: hibernate

Working with `Hibernate`. `User` object is having one to many relation with `Role`. I wan to save User with roles, Kindly give me some examples.

**User.java :**

```
@ Entity 
@ Table(name="user") 
public class User implements Serializable { 

  @ ManyToOne 
  @ JoinColumn(name="userTypeId") 
  private UserType userType; 
  //setters and getters

 }
```

**UserType.java:**

```
@ Entity 
@ Table(name="userType") 
public class UserType {

@ Id 
@ Column(name="userTypeId") 
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY) 
private int userTypeId; 

@ OneToMany(mappedBy="userType") 
private Set<User> users = new HashSet<User>(); 
//setters and getters

}
```

**UserDaoImpl.java**

```
@Repository("UserDao") 
public class UserDaoImpl extends AbstractDaoImpl<User, Integer> implements UserDao{     

@Autowired 
UserTypeDao userTypeDao; 
public User createUser(UserSignUpModel userSignupModel) throws BusinessException,SystemException { 
user = new User(); 
user.setUserType((UserType) getCurrentSession().get(UserType.class, ServerConstants.NEWLY_CREATED));
}
}
```

**ERROR:**

```
org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity: com.gff.server.entity.UserType
```

gff-servlet.xml entry

```
<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.gff.entity" />
    <!-- <property name="configLocation">
        <value>classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml</value>
    </property> -->
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${jdbc.dialect}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Comment: Simple google search gave me these links : [**ONE**](http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-one-to-many-relationship-example/) [**TWO**](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/hibernate-one-to-many-xml-mapping-tutorial/) [**THREE**](http://www.dzone.com/tutorials/java/hibernate/hibernate-example/hibernate-mapping-one-to-many-1.html)

Comment: Does UserType come under com.gff.entity ? , can you see that a table for it has been created in the DB on server start up ?